# How to Reduce max_connections value in Postgres Cluster?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have three node cluster.

Now, I want to reduce the `max_connections` field from `300` to `100`. I have changed the value in both master and replica in `postgresql.conf` file. I have restarted my master first than the other replica nodes. everything seems ok in master but replicas are shutting down automatically.

Here is the error:  `hot standby is not possible because max_connections = 100 is a lower setting than on the master server (its value was 300)`

I have found a solution where need to start as `hot_standby=off`.

Is there any other solution rather than this?

Comment: Did you changed it to 100 on both master and replica?

Comment: setting hot_standby to `off` will not allow you to query(read) your replica.

Comment: yes, i have changed to 100 for both master and replica. 

> setting hot_standby to off will not allow you to query(read) your replica. thats why i need the value `on`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Basically what happened we can't start Replica with less `max_connections` value than Primary when we have set `hot_standby = on`.

Though i have updated The Primary server's `max_connections` The information didn't arrive in Replica side. Normally, Primary server's config changes are notified with wal log changes. For this reason, after restarting the primary with lower `max_connections` we need to wait for write operations and then change the Replica's `max_connecions`.

But i think this one is not a feasible solution.

**Better Solution:**

1. Start the Primary with lower max_connections
2. Start replica's with `hot_standby = off` (if the server stucked in starting state, after few second don't wait for start)
3. Shut down the replica
4. Start replica's with `hot_standby = on`

Answer (score 1):

As you are changing `max_connections`,

Stop all instances, change `max_connections` setting `postgresql.conf` in all three nodes.

1. Start master
2. Then start replica

Comment: I have tried that. I already mention this . But this didn't work. thanks for your response

Comment: Did you tried `SHOW max_connections` on master?

Comment: yes. master's max_connections is as desired i mean 100.

Comment: Try starting the standby with 300, let it attach to the primary, then restart it with a setting of 100.